# Does a differentiable function map open intervals to open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that preimages are open for open images, since differentiability implies continuity. I suspect there is a counterexample to the above though. This is not homework, just study.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin x$ maps the open interval $(-2\pi,2\pi)$ to no open interval $[-1,1]$

Comment: Ah, I see. Nice. Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=x^2$ and the open interval $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for an ideally simple counterexample. I will check this answered as soon as the system lets me.